# What is the difference between void* (*)() and void*?

Tags: c++, pointers, types, microcontroller, avr

In one of my programs, I'm getting the error

```
invalid conversion from 'void* (*)()' to 'void*' [-fpermissive]
```

I'm trying to understand the difference between these two data types. It is very confusing.

What I think that these data types are:
`void* (*)()` So this data type is a pointer to a void (`void*`) which also has another pointer (`(*)`), and for some odd reason, it has empty parentheses. So What I imagine the memory for this data type looks like is `|--void address--|--pointer of unknown type--|--something denoting no arguments--|`

then there's `void*`. This seems simple, and it only represents the address of a function. The memory model should be as simple as `|--void address--|`.

Why this is so weird, is that the function that is thrown the error is as follows.

```
void callFunction(void *voidThing){
void *testVariable = voidThing;
}
```

And as far as I am aware, this creates a testVariable of type pointer, and that pointer is to a void.
This function also takes in a parameter of type pointer, and that pointer is also to a void.

Why is the compiler throwing an error, even though the local variable is of the same type of the parameter? What is the difference between the variables in terms of the memory footprint of the two?

Comment: "for some odd reason, it has empty parentheses"  - hint: think about where else you would find empty parentheses in C++

Comment: @JesperJuhl so then what is `void *()`?

Comment: @M.M so then if I want to create an object which is a pointer to a function of name `{name}` and return type `{retObject}` and it takes in an object of type `{paramObj}`, the declaration would look like `{retObject} {name} *({paramObj});` ?

Comment: I changed my comments to an answer, which happens to answer your last question too

Comment: There is a cdecl tool (and source code of it) which allows to "decode" those complex types. https://cdecl.org/ The problem is it requires  ids within C string, i.e. `void * (*p) ()`

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Funnily enough, "void* (*)()" doesn't work in it :-)

Comment: @tuskiomi it requires full declaration with an id of variable, `void* (*p)()`. I think, it'd be easy to enhance to code to let it find most nested point in the string without help of var-name

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are *types*:

- `void *` - pointer to void  (this can point to any object, not to a function)
- `void * ()` - function taking no arguments and returning `void *`
- `void * (*) ()` - pointer to function taking no arguments and returning `void *`

Example of a declaration of an identifier for each of the above, respectively:

```
void *object_ptr;    // variable: pointer to object

void *function();    // function  (not a variable)

void * (*function_pointer)();  // variable: pointer to function
```

The syntax for function types places the identifier before the argument list , a similar thing happens with arrays. This is called *infix notation*.

Pointer declarators are *postfix*, i.e. the identifier comes after the `*` .

In `void * (*) ()` the first set of parentheses are necessary because `void * *()` would be a different type (the declaration grammar results in `void * *` staying together).

---

The `callFunction` function is correct in itself, however the error message probably comes from trying to call this with incorrect argument, e.g. the address of a function. `void *` can only hold the address of an object .

Some platforms may allow `reinterpret_cast` to be used to cast an object pointer to a function pointer or vice versa, this feature is *conditionally-supported with implementation-defined semantics*, meaning that implementations may or may not allow it, but must document the behaviour if they do.

Comment: So this is great, and very helpful, but how do these differ in memory footprint? It seems the first can contain any data, and is unbounded. It seems the second can also contain any data, so long as it is executable, and is also unbounded. And it seems that the third one contains a single memory address, and a function signature, which can be dereferenced to call the function.

Comment: @tuskiomi the function signature is  part of the type, it doesn't consume storage (this applies to all variables, their memory footprint represents the stored data and the compiler keeps track of types).  On typical LP64 systems both will be 64-bits,  but on some systems one will be 32-bit while the other is 64-bit , and historically other combinations have existed too

Comment: Also, does this mean that `(*) ()` is a valid object type? What should I Google to learn more. Pointers have always confused me.

Comment: @tuskiomi  `(*)()` isn't anything. My answer gives three different valid examples. Maybe googling function pointers would help; you can read cppreference.com or the C++ Standard, or this site,  perhaps for more useful answers than a general google search would give (they tend to pull up all sorts of incorrect dreck that people have written and SEO'd)

Comment: what about `void * (*) (*) ()` or even more meta `void * (*) (void * (*) ())`

Comment: I'm clearly not getting something basic here. I just don't know where to look for more information

Comment: @tuskiomi [try here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/declarations)  , or look up "C declaration syntax" . This aspect of the syntax is the same in C as C++

Comment: `void * (*) (void * (*) ())`  is `void * (*)(params)` where params is `void *(*)()`,  we know what both of those are (my answer covers)  , so it is pointer to function returning `void *` and taking parameter of type: pointer to function returning `void *` taking no arguments

Comment: and because void * can be any object, it can also be nothing.. it makes sense.

Comment: `void * (*) (*) ()` is a syntax error.every type can be made up by starting from a simpler type and "adding" pointer / function / array types or parentheses, but those are added according to the postfix or infix rules .   If you have a valid declaration `blablabla p blablabla;`  (where the bla could be any symbols, possibly empty), then `blablabla (*q) blablabla;` is a pointer to whatever type `p` had. The parentheses might be redundant or necessary depending on what came before

Comment: @tuskiomi `void *` can't be nothing , it is a type . The "no arguments" in my previous comment comes from the `()` at the end . The address stored in a `void *` variable must be the address of an object  or a null pointer (and there are some invalid values too but that's getting a bit far afield)

Comment: @tuskiomi cannot be if it's `void*` because * means pointer.  Depends on language as several languages got same syntax, absence of void mean different things. In C absence of return type was meant `int` and absence of `void` in parameter list meant that function can take any arguments. C++ doesn't allow both and `()` is equal to `(void)`. If I recall right, Object C had rules close to C++,  General rule of c-declaration  that you have to start from inside and go outward, first toward right side in search of `(argument-list)` , `[array-size]`  or closing parent, then go left, then exit parents.

Comment: Re: "how do these differ in memory footprint" -- `void*p` points to **data**. `void (*p)()` points to **code**. Formally, you cannot convert one to the other, which is why the compiler is giving that warning. On some systems the two are inter-convertible, and that conversion is meaningful and useful.